Error in STM32CubeIDE
I have this error. What could be the reason?
09:27:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project button2 ****
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.12.1\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.200.202301161003\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe:F:\alireza\amali\TuochGFX\button2\button2\STM32F429VETX_FLASH.ld:90: non constant or forward reference address expression for section .ARM.extab
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:109: button2.elf] Error 1
"make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:28:22 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 22s.677ms)


There is a support forum for STMCubeIDE on https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubeide-mcus/bd-p/stm32-mcu-cubeide-forum: I think that is where this question belongs.

It seems you have problem with incremental build option, try the solution below

